# Focus follow mouse

Tags: mouse

I use mouse wheel scroll on two panes. In order to focus one pane, I must first click to focus it, then scroll.

Is there a way to focus upon mouse moving? This is also known as `Focus follow mouse` in i3wm.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4):

In  GVim there are `set mousefocus` and `set scrollfocus` (only Windows GVim 8.1.2257 or later).

`mousefocus` automatically activates window so it gets both mouse and keyboard input; `scrollfocus` only allows scrolling window under mouse cursor without activating it.

For Neovim it seems to work out-of-the-box (as if `set scrollfocus`).

Comment: On Windows, you also need to `:set scrollfocus`, but this needs a relative recent Vim 8.1.2257

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Not exactly. They both can be used independently. I'll update my answer.